# PHP GeoIP redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, geoip

I have configured geoip redirection via apache module and everything works fine. All traffic from specific country is redirected to desired URL, but I want to put URL link on country specific site to come back to main website. so that when visitor clicks on main website's URL, the should be allowed to remain on main website URL. All major Multi national websites have this feature, can anybody help with this.

UK visitor visits domain.com and is redirected to domain.co.uk

UK Visitor is given choice as a link on top to go back to domain.com

**Edited:**
I was succesffuly able to use below code to redirect visitor to country specific URL and then allow the visitor to visit back the main URL by passing referrer=domain.in parameter as shown below. BUT NOW THE ISSUE IS: When visitor visits other links or pages of the main website after returning from domain.in URL, he is redirected back to domain.in as per below code. So how I can keep the visitor on main website or same website which he is visiting through referrer parameter.

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (false !== strpos($url,'domain.in')) {

} else {
    include("geoip/geoip.inc");

$gi = geoip_open("geoip/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if($country_code == 'IN')
{
header('Location: http://domain.in');
exit();
}
else
{
header('Location: http://domain.com');
exit();
}
geoip_close($gi);
}
```

Comment: `Referer` is unreliable. You could try cookies, but visitors with those disabled suffer the same problem. Why not employ the same tactic as on the country specific site? (Offer a big visible option on the main site to go to the country specific site)

Comment: big visible option is an option, but if you look at expedia.com or other sites, which perform well, I was just wondering what they are doing to achieve that?

Comment: With cookies. I would not like at that site as a shining example on how things should be done though.

Comment: can you help me with cookie, I will just give a try, the visible option is the last option and avoidable option, for me.

Comment: Recipe: redirect if no cookie OR special GET variable present, make a link on the country-specific site with a certain GET variable, on receiving a request on the main site WITH that GET variable, set cookie, don't redirect (or: redirect to site without the GET variable as the cookie should now work and it looks cleaner to people).

Comment: Can you help me with code, I am newbie to this and could not comprehend your suggestion. Please.

Comment: Can you share your best effort implementing it in your answer so I can see where exactly you no longer can follow my (granted, terse) suggestion?